# Error in Spark sql : AnalysisException: Correlated scalar subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am creating a spark dataframe using the below query:

```
select distinct  adr.ProductionDate,adr.CostCenterKey,adr.AEMainCategoryKey, Sum(adr.DurationDayFrac*adr.FixedCashCostAE)*100 / (select sum(adr_sub.DurationDayFrac*adr_sub.FixedCashCostAE) 
from hive_metastore.oth_opsdbconf.operations_db___asset_effectiveness_daily_reporting  adr_sub
where adr_sub.costcenterkey=adr.costcenterkey and adr_sub.ProductionDate=adr.ProductionDate
) as AELossMagnitude 
FROM hive_metastore.oth_opsdbconf.operations_db___asset_effectiveness_daily_reporting  adr 
WHERE adr.DurationDayFrac != 0 AND adr.ProductionDate <= Current_Date() 
AND adr.ProductionDate >= '2017-01-01'
AND adr.SiteName in ('Ludwigshafen','Schwarzheide','Antwerpen') 
AND AreaIsCurrent = 'true' 
group by adr.ProductionDate,adr.CostCenterKey,adr.AEMainCategoryKey
order by adr.ProductionDate,adr.CostCenterKey,adr.AEMainCategoryKey
```

But i am getting the below error:

AnalysisException: Correlated scalar subquery 'scalarsubquery(adr.costcenterkey, adr.ProductionDate)' is neither present in the group by, nor in an aggregate function. Add it to group by using ordinal position or wrap it in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;

Request you to please help me with the correct syntax.

I am expecting the correct syntax to remove the error.z
Its asking for group by in the sub query which is not possible.

Comment: "Its asking for group by in the sub query which is not possible." Why is that not possible? Why not just `JOIN` the reporting table? Also, why do you use `DISTINCT` when you already `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Removing DISTINCT does not make any difference.Can you please help me how to JOIN with the reporting table.

Comment: The join should be easy enough, just join on the columns you now use in the subquery

Comment: My point about `DISTINCT` is more that it doesn't (shouldn't) make a difference, and (no offense intended) it usually means you don't quite understand what the code actually does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't understand why you need the distinct key word.  I think the correlated sub-query will not work.  Use a common table expression instead.  Please see code below.

```
--
--  Use common table expression instead of correlated sub query
--

WITH cte_cost_by_center_n_date
(
SELECT
   costcenterkey,
   ProductionDate,
   sum(DurationDayFrac * FixedCashCostAE) as TotalCost

FROM
    hive_metastore.oth_opsdbconf.operations_db___asset_effectiveness_daily_reporting 
GROUP BY
   costcenterkey,
   ProductionDate
)

SELECT
    adr.ProductionDate,
    adr.CostCenterKey,
    adr.AEMainCategoryKey, 
    sum(adr.DurationDayFrac*adr.FixedCashCostAE) * 100 /  adr_sub.TotalCost as AELossMagnitude 
FROM 
    hive_metastore.oth_opsdbconf.operations_db___asset_effectiveness_daily_reporting as adr 
JOIN
    cte_cost_by_center_n_date as adr_sub
ON 
    adr_sub.costcenterkey = adr.costcenterkey 
    AND adr_sub.ProductionDate = adr.ProductionDate
WHERE 
    adr.DurationDayFrac != 0 
    AND adr.ProductionDate <= Current_Date() 
    AND adr.ProductionDate >= '2017-01-01'
    AND adr.SiteName in ('Ludwigshafen','Schwarzheide','Antwerpen') 
    AND adr.AreaIsCurrent = 'true' 
GROUP BY
    adr.ProductionDate,
    adr.CostCenterKey,
    adr.AEMainCategoryKey
ORDER BY 
    adr.ProductionDate,
    adr.CostCenterKey,
    adr.AEMainCategoryKey
```

Comment: I modified the query little based on few basic errors.Now again its throwing the similar kind of error:                                                                                        --

Error Message: 
AnalysisException: expression 'adr_sub.TotalCost' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;

Comment: @FaizanArefin why did you accept the answer if it didn't work?

Comment: I fixed the CTE but it is the concept you should worry about, not the details.  I am trying in my own tenant with the adventure works dataset.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need a cte at all, just a straight join would do

Comment: The CTE makes it cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data set that I have locally, Adventure works.  Let's figure out sales at the company level regardless of region.

```
select 
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    sum(s.SalesAmount) as CompanyAmt
from 
    star.fact_internet_sales as s
join 
    star.dim_date as d
on 
    s.OrderDateKey = d.DateKey
where 
    d.CalendarYear = 2013
group by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter
order by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter
```

[image]

Next, lets figure out sales are the regional level (territory).

```
select 
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey,
    sum(s.SalesAmount) as RegionAmt
from 
    star.fact_internet_sales as s
join 
    star.dim_date as d
on 
    s.OrderDateKey = d.DateKey
where 
    d.CalendarYear = 2013
group by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey
order by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey
```

[image]
Last, use the CTE to bring in a total so that we can figure out what percentage does each territory contribute to sales for a given quarter.

```
-- Sales per qtr at company level
with cte_whole_company as
(
select 
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    sum(s.SalesAmount) as CompanyAmt
from 
    star.fact_internet_sales as s
join 
    star.dim_date as d
on 
    s.OrderDateKey = d.DateKey
where 
    d.CalendarYear = 2013
group by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter
order by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter
)
-- Aggregated sales at territory with pct/contribution
select 
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey,
    sum(s.SalesAmount) as RegionAmt,
    first(c.CompanyAmt) as CompanyAmt,
    sum(s.SalesAmount) / first(c.CompanyAmt) * 100 as PctAmt
from 
    star.fact_internet_sales as s
join 
    star.dim_date as d
on 
    s.OrderDateKey = d.DateKey
join
    cte_whole_company as c
on 
    d.CalendarYear = c.CalendarYear and
    d.CalendarQuarter = c.CalendarQuarter
where 
    d.CalendarYear = 2013
group by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey
order by
    d.CalendarYear,
    d.CalendarQuarter,
    s.SalesTerritoryKey
```

My original statement that sub-queries can not be used in aggregations is true.  Yes, you might be able to create a derived query or even create a temporary view, but I like common table expressions.

[image]

Comment: Hi Crafty,It worked for me too.There was a slight change in the query .There was a Group By missing in the TotalCost.After adding it i got the desired result.